# Uniform convergence of a partial when we have uniform acotation but no equicotinuity

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

I have $x_n(t)=\sin(nt)$ with $t \in [0,2\pi]$,
and I have to prove that there's no $ \sigma:\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ such that $x_{\sigma(n)}(t)$ converges for every $t$.

I have proved that there's no pointwise convergence, but I'm stuck at uniform convergence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try proof by contradiction:
supposing that theres a $\sigma$ you get:
$$x_{\sigma(n)}(t)\rightarrow x_0$$
Now you pick a function $f \in C^1$ with compact support .
Then, using chain rule you get $$\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}{\sin(nt)f(t)}dt=\frac{1}{n}\int \cos(nt)f'(t)dt$$ then you have:$$\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}{\sin(nt)f(t)}dt\rightarrow 0$$so
$$x_{\sigma(n)}(t)\rightarrow x_0(t)$$
$$\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}{x_0(t)f(t)}dt= 0 \Longrightarrow x_0(t)\equiv0 \ a.e.$$
On the other hand you have:
$$\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}{\sin^2(nt)}dt=\pi\Longrightarrow  $$
so $$\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}{x_0^2(t)}dt=\pi  $$
and this is impossible because  $x_0(t)\equiv0 \ a.e$